# Pull data from multiple columns into one column

Tags: join, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

A [link](https://docs.google.com/a/asfg.edu.mx/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AocLpixK8R2QdFQyOERCTjlyOTFTa3daSnRTWEJUM1E#gid=3) to a Google Sheets in which students signed up for workshops for our career fair. I'm trying to make attendance lists for each workshop during each session. You can see my attempt on the Session 1 tab. In the header row, I have each of the workshop names for that session, and I would like the list of students below it.

When I use the following query, I end up with data across multiple columns because I'm drawing the students' names from the grade level columns on the response tab. This is really inconvenient because I just want one column of data with all of the students listed for that workshop.

```
=query('Form Responses'!D:O, "select D, F, H, J where O='Architect'")
```

Is there a way to pull the list of students signed up for Architecture during the first session from multiple columns on Form Responses tab into one column on the Session 1 tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to previous answer, also try:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(query('Form Responses'!D:O, "select D, F, H, J where O='Architect'")&char(10)),char(10))))
```

This formula should output 1 column. See if it works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the entire formula in `=Concatenate()`

```
=Concatenate(query('Form Responses'!D:O, "select D, F, H, J where O='Architect'"))
```